# How to fix this error in EF7?

Tags: c#, windows, entity-framework, visual-studio, entity-framework-core

I am trying to get started with `EF7`.

[This is the example](https://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/platforms/full-dotnet/new-db.html) I am trying to run right now.

I am getting the following error:

[image]

This is my `packages.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework.Commands" version="7.0.0-rc1-final" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="EntityFramework.Core" version="7.0.0-rc1-final" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="EntityFramework.Relational" version="7.0.0-rc1-final" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="EntityFramework.Relational.Design" version="7.0.0-rc1-final" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="EntityFramework.SqlServer" version="7.0.0-beta8" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="EntityFramework.SqlServer.Design" version="7.0.0-beta8" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Ix-Async" version="1.2.5" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions" version="1.0.0-rc1-final" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory" version="1.0.0-rc1-final" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" version="1.0.0-rc1-final" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" version="1.0.0-rc1-final" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder" version="1.0.0-rc1-final" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" version="1.0.0-rc1-final" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" version="1.0.0-rc1-final" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" version="1.0.0-rc1-final" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" version="1.0.0-rc1-final" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.OptionsModel" version="1.0.0-rc1-final" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives" version="1.0.0-rc1-final" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Remotion.Linq" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Collections.Immutable" version="1.1.36" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" version="4.0.0-beta-23516" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Tracing" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Runtime" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Threading" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

As you can see `EF.Core` is already declared here.

I am also having an Warning

```
The 'packages' element is not declared.
```

So what is the problem?

Note: I am using `Windows 10 Pro` and `VS Enterprise 2015`.

Comment: Can't get it to reproduce, and I'm basically on the same setup.  One difference between our projects, mine doesn't reference either EntityFramework.SqlServer or EntityFramework.SqlServer.Design.  Mine only references EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer.  -- Not sure if that's related though.

Comment: @DanOrlovsky, OK. I have just tried with `EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer`   it is giving the same error.

Comment: just found this: https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/41

may be related to your problem.

Comment: Try changing the OnConfiguring signature to: protected override OnConfiguring(EntityOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)

Comment: @DanOrlovsky, Nope. It doesn't work. I am using rc1. They were talking about beta 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must remove the EF.SqlServer and install the EF.MicrosoftSqlServer package instead, as you cannot mix beta8 and rc1 components